# save octave figure to stdout?

Tags: image, plot, octave, figure

I'd like to:

```
saveas(gcf, "/dev/stdout", "svg");
```

to save the current figure to stdout as a svg image. The current workaround is:

```
temp_filename = [tempname(), '.svg'];
saveas(gcf, temp_filename);
fwrite(1, uint8(fileread(temp_filename)));
% disp(fileread(temp_filename));
delete(temp_filename);
```

Otherwise, there is an error:

```
error: print: cannot open file /dev/stdout.svg for writing
error: called from
    print at line 447 column 7
    saveas at line 150 column 5
```

How can I do this without an intermediate file?